# Why doesn't my ftp upload in php work?

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
        $ftp_user_name='user'; 
        $ftp_user_pass='pass'; 
        $ftp_server='ip.addr.ess';
        $ftp_dir='/site.com/public_html/upload/'; //www.site.com/upload/
        $upload_file='some.txt';

        $destination_file=$ftp_dir.$upload_file; 

        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

        $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $upload_file, FTP_BINARY);
```

Nothing gets uploaded, but the file exists on my server.

What am I missing?

Comment: How should we know?  Show us the errors you're getting!  Fire up a packet sniffer and do some basic debugging first.  Try Wireshark.

Comment: I don't get any errors... I'm checking that the file exists on my server but don't know what kind of commands I can send over to the remote server to get back any errors

Comment: What does your packet trace say?

Comment: @Brad, surely you don't think someone having such a basic problem can easily use a packet sniffer?

Comment: @chris, I do!  It's not complicated... click start, stop when done, and type in "ftp" to filter, and click "follow tcp stream".  This is a debugging technique that if someone doesn't know, they should learn.  It isn't hard, and is well documented.  If the poster would spend 2 minutes doing this, the question would likely be answered immediately.

Comment: var_dump($login_result);

Comment: is this a place to get answers or to debate how skilled i might be

Answer (score 0):

Does your FTP user have write permission on the destination server?